# SQL : splitting a row in two rows

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have a table that looks like this

```
|  ID  |   item1   |   item 2  | 
|   1  |     A1    |     B1    |
|   2  |     A2    |     B2    |
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
|  ID  |   item  |
|   1  |    A1   |
|   1  |    B1   |
|   2  |    A2   |
|   2  |    B2   |
```

In some sense it is the inverse to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298698/get-two-rows-from-two-different-select-statements).

Comment: select item1 UNION ALL select item2

Comment: Thanks, this solved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT ID, item1 AS item
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT ID, item2 AS item
FROM mytable
ORDER BY ID, item
```